# "autossh" output change under "expect"

Tags: expect, autossh

I am using autossh with a monitoring flag. autossh prints to standard output every time it send test packets.

When using autossh under expect the text packets messages are not printed.
I don't know if they are sent at all which is important to keep the ssh connection alive.

can you tell if "expect" effects the autossh behavior ?
how can I figure out if autossh works correctly ?

the expect code:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 50
spawn autossh -M 11111 -N -R 4848:localhost:80 user@192.168.1.100
set keepRunning 1
while {$keepRunning} {      
    expect \
    {
        "(yes/no)"    { send "yes\r" }  
        "Password:*"  { send "1234\r" ; set keepRunning 0 }

        "ssh exited prematurely with" { exit 7 }
        "remote port forwarding failed*"  { exit 8 }
    }
}
expect \
{
    "remote port forwarding failed*"  { exit 9 }
    "Password:*"  { exit 5 }
}
wait
```

---

the periodic output that I see without expect is this:

```
autossh[2882]: checking for grace period, tries = 0
autossh[2882]: starting ssh (count 1)
autossh[2883]: execing /pfrm2.0/bin/ssh
autossh[2882]: ssh child pid is 2883
autossh[2882]: check on child 2883
autossh[2882]: set alarm for 50 secs
Password: autossh[2882]: connection ok
**autossh[2882]: check on child 2883
autossh[2882]: set alarm for 60 secs
autossh[2882]: connection ok
autossh[2882]: check on child 2883
autossh[2882]: set alarm for 60 secs**
```

The last 5 lines are test packets sent by autossh.
That lines are printed only when running autossh from bash directly.
When running from using "expect" those lines are not printed and I dont know if autossh sends them.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code what you have tried ?

Comment: I've added the code in the original message. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, I have not worked on `autossh` before. But, as per your code, `expect` will check for the patterns given by you, such as logging in by means of providing the password. If it happen to see an sort of error message. it will exit.

Then at the end. you have added `wait`. It delays until a spawned process (or the current process if none is named) terminates. I am not sure whether those prints will simply get printed in terminal. In that case, after logging in, you can make the `expect` to wait for it just like how you did for logging in.  If those prints will be seen after providing any sort of command, then make sure you passing it by `send` and then wait for those patterns.

Unless until, you instruct `expect` to expect for a pattern, it won't bother waiting for anything which is why it won't be seen in output as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't need the text itself, it is just an indication that the "autossh" running correctly. and I use "wait" to monitor autossh gone down.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that wait somehow prevents the "autossh" from monitoring the connection.
The "wait" in the end of the "expect" script was replaced with "interact" and it is working fine now.

* Thanks Dinesh

Comment: Great, Ozma. That `wait` will simply wait for the `autossh` to get closed. Earlier I thought I trying to close it and waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more detailed description and answer.)

What I wanted:

1. ssh tunnel using autossh and expect and a wrapper bash script.
2. The bash script should run in background.
3. when the ssh quits the script should start the tunnel again.

The problems with expect:
After establishing the ssh-tunnel I have tried using the following

1. interact - when the bash script was running in background **interact** hangs so expect wasn't waiting for autossh and I couldn't monitor the autossh (without a sleep loop)
2. wait - for some reason it was preventing autossh monitoring mechanism from working properly.
3. -nothing- - expect just quits and I couldn't monitor autossh

the solution was using this loop end "expecting" a "connection ok" string

```
    set moreThanAutoSshTimeout [expr {$env(AUTOSSH_POLL) + 10}]
    set timeout $moreThanAutoSshTimeout
    set connStatus 1
    while { $connStatus } {
        set connStatus 0
        expect \
        {
            "connection ok"    { set connStatus 1 }
        }
    }
```